90 red balls and 10 blue balls randomly put into groups of 10, probability of a group having 6 or more blue balls
If I have 100 balls where 90 are red and 10 are blue and I randomly assign balls into 10 groups of 10. How do I calculate the probaility of exactly one group having 6 or more blue balls?

Note that it is impossible for two or more groups to each have at least $6$ blue balls.  That makes life a lot easier.  What's the probability that group $#1$ has at least $6$ blue balls?
